# Uploading a db file on server in android

Tags: php, android, http-post

I am uploading the db file from my app data directory. The server always returns the ERROR message. I do not know the reason. Please help me out.

Here is my android code:

```
  String URL="http://hazelrink.com/apps/Sandbox/upload1.php";

     String databasePath = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("4C1A_14.db").getPath();
        File f = new File(databasePath);


    HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost p = new HttpPost(URL);

        try {
            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                    new FileInputStream(f), -1);

             reqEntity.setContentType("multipart/form-data");

            reqEntity.setChunked(true); // 
          ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        p.setEntity(reqEntity);

          String r= c.execute(p,responseHandler);
         status = r;
        Log.i("Login", status);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The server script is this:

```
<?php 
$uploaddir = '4CA1_BR/'; 
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file; 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { 
   echo "SU"; 
} 
else { 
   echo "ER"; 
} 
?>
```

I always get "ER" as response in my app!
I am also sharing the objective C code that works fine in the iphone:

```
        NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date]; //current date
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY-HH:mm:ss"]; //format it 
        dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate]; //save it an a variable

        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", [appDelegate username], dateString]; //name of the database file that is going to be uploaded to the server

        //this part

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
        NSString *databaseStringer;
        for (NSString *s in fileList){
            databaseStringer = s;
        }

        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseStringer];
        NSData *dataBaseData = [NSData alloc];
        dataBaseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        //this part //this part above (between the blue text) explains how it gets the database and convert it into bytes and store it in a temporary variable

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://hazelrink.com/apps/Sandbox/upload1.php”]; // the Synchro URL
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //set up the POST method

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary]; //%@ in objective-C refers to string so in this case the boundry string is included in the contenttype string
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        //the above code is included as a header when doing POSTing. Take note of the value and header

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"%@.db\"\r\n",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataBaseData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        //take note of what is being passed in the body

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //result are below. there is only two result. if ‘SU’ then proceed to doing another method.

        if ([returnString isEqualToString:@"ER"]){
            myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unexpected Error Occured!"
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [myAlertView show];
        }
        else if ([returnString isEqualToString:@"SU"]){
            [self writerSQL]; //second part
        }
```

Comment: Have you create `4CA1_BR` this name folder where you have created this web-service???

Comment: no.Why should I create that folder?

Comment: Because basically that is the directory where your .db is going to uplpad. Just create the same name folder on server exactly there where you have your web-service

Comment: I have shared the iPhone code for this. Please confirm that folder is necessary.

Comment: is your iPhone code is uploading your file to server?

Comment: Yes the file is uploaded through iphone